# PayPal integration android

Tags: android, paypal

Steps I followed to integrate paypal.

- Created account in sandbox.
- Created ClientId for the app.
- downloaded paypal sdk and integrated with my app.
- followed steps as in `https://devblog.paypal.com/working-with-the-new-android-sdk/` for integration.

Code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private static final String CONFIG_ENVIRONMENT = PayPalConfiguration.ENVIRONMENT_NO_NETWORK;
    private static final String CONFIG_CLIENT_ID = "***************************";
    private static final String CONFIG_RECEIVER_EMAIL = "test-facilitator@officialgates.com";
     private static final int REQUEST_CODE_PAYMENT = 1;
     private static final String TAG = "paymentExample";


      private static PayPalConfiguration config = new PayPalConfiguration()
      .environment(CONFIG_ENVIRONMENT)
      .clientId(CONFIG_CLIENT_ID)
  .merchantName("Store");


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }


     public void onBuyPressed(View pressed) {
            PayPalPayment thingToBuy = getThingToBuy(PayPalPayment.PAYMENT_INTENT_SALE);


            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, PaymentActivity.class);
               intent.putExtra(PayPalService.EXTRA_PAYPAL_CONFIGURATION, config);
               intent.putExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_PAYMENT, thingToBuy);
               startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_PAYMENT);
        }

        private PayPalPayment getThingToBuy(String paymentIntent) {
            return new PayPalPayment(new BigDecimal("100.75"), "USD", "my product",
                    paymentIntent);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_PAYMENT) {
                if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    PaymentConfirmation confirm =
                            data.getParcelableExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_RESULT_CONFIRMATION);
                    if (confirm != null) {
                        try {
                            Log.i(TAG, confirm.toJSONObject().toString(4));
                            Log.i(TAG, confirm.getPayment().toJSONObject().toString(4));


                            JSONObject jsonObj=new JSONObject(confirm.toJSONObject().toString());

                            String paymentId=jsonObj.getJSONObject("response").getString("id");
                            System.out.println("payment id:-=="+paymentId);


                            Toast.makeText(
                                    getApplicationContext(),
                                    "payment id"+paymentId, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                    .show();   


                            Toast.makeText(
                                    getApplicationContext(),
                                    "PaymentConfirmation info received from PayPal", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                    .show();

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            Log.e(TAG, "an extremely unlikely failure occurred: ", e);
                        }
                    }
                } else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "The user canceled.");
                } else if (resultCode == PaymentActivity.RESULT_EXTRAS_INVALID) {
                    Log.i(
                            TAG,
                            "An invalid Payment or PayPalConfiguration was submitted. Please see the docs.");
                }
            } 

        }
        @Override
        public void onDestroy() {
            // Stop service when done
            stopService(new Intent(this, PayPalService.class));
            super.onDestroy();
        }
}
```

Response:

```
01-20 01:14:43.072: I/paymentExample(17759): {
01-20 01:14:43.072: I/paymentExample(17759):     "response": {
01-20 01:14:43.072: I/paymentExample(17759):         "state": "approved",
01-20 01:14:43.072: I/paymentExample(17759):         "id": "PAY-6PU626847BSKPEWXHY",
01-20 01:14:43.072: I/paymentExample(17759):         "create_time": "2014-07-18T18:46:55Z",
01-20 01:14:43.072: I/paymentExample(17759):         "intent": "sale"
01-20 01:14:43.072: I/paymentExample(17759):     },
01-20 01:14:43.072: I/paymentExample(17759):     "client": {
01-20 01:14:43.072: I/paymentExample(17759):         "platform": "Android",
01-20 01:14:43.072: I/paymentExample(17759):         "paypal_sdk_version": "2.8.4",
01-20 01:14:43.072: I/paymentExample(17759):         "product_name": "PayPal-Android-SDK",
01-20 01:14:43.072: I/paymentExample(17759):         "environment": "mock"
01-20 01:14:43.072: I/paymentExample(17759):     },
01-20 01:14:43.072: I/paymentExample(17759):     "response_type": "payment"
01-20 01:14:43.072: I/paymentExample(17759): }
01-20 01:14:43.073: I/paymentExample(17759): {
01-20 01:14:43.073: I/paymentExample(17759):     "short_description": "YRYCN",
01-20 01:14:43.073: I/paymentExample(17759):     "amount": "100.75",
01-20 01:14:43.073: I/paymentExample(17759):     "intent": "sale",
01-20 01:14:43.073: I/paymentExample(17759):     "currency_code": "USD"
01-20 01:14:43.073: I/paymentExample(17759): }
```

My questions:

- Response remains same no matter how many times I run, that is PaymentId and create_time remains the same. Please let me know why this is happening?
- How to implement this point - `From your server, use the payment id value to look up the payment details with the REST API.` ?
- Is it Possible to use only "Pay with Card" option from PayPal SDK?

Comment: Please use proper sentence case when writing questions on stackoverflow. Also, [this](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2429/can-doubt-sometimes-mean-question) might interest you.

Comment: Thanks but got any related answers for the above question?

Comment: I am still stuck with the bug...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer and had done very small mistake.

- Response remains same because i was checking without sandbox/Real Money option ie.

[this is for without communicating to PayPal's servers ]

```
private static final String CONFIG_ENVIRONMENT = PayPalConfiguration.ENVIRONMENT_NO_NETWORK
```

Change to

[this is for to your test credentials
     from https://developer.paypal.com ]

```
private static final String CONFIG_ENVIRONMENT = PayPalConfiguration.ENVIRONMENT_SANDBOX
```

or Change to

[this is to move real money]

```
private static final String CONFIG_ENVIRONMENT = PayPalConfiguration.ENVIRONMENT_PRODUCTION
```

** not sure on rest two points